# org.apache.hudi.exception.HoodieUpsertException: Failed to upsert for commit time - PySpark Unable to Write to Hudi with ABFS

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark

I am using using a [Spark on k8 Operator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator) to submit spark applications to an executor and driver. When trying to write the results of the application back to azure storage I am getting the following error.

Using the following jar versions on the executor and driver

- com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:8.6.6
- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:3.3.1
- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:3.3.1
- org.apache.hudi:hudi-spark3-bundle_2.12:0.10.0

Has anyone seen this before or is currently dealing with this?

Full Error:

```
Writing to abfs://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/folder/host
22/06/08 20:45:15 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
Hudi write failed: host
An error occurred while calling o146.save.
: org.apache.hudi.exception.HoodieUpsertException: Failed to upsert for commit time 20220608204512566
at org.apache.hudi.table.action.commit.AbstractWriteHelper.write(AbstractWriteHelper.java:62)
at org.apache.hudi.table.action.commit.SparkUpsertCommitActionExecutor.execute(SparkUpsertCommitActionExecutor.java:46)
at org.apache.hudi.table.HoodieSparkCopyOnWriteTable.upsert(HoodieSparkCopyOnWriteTable.java:119)
at org.apache.hudi.table.HoodieSparkCopyOnWriteTable.upsert(HoodieSparkCopyOnWriteTable.java:103)
at org.apache.hudi.client.SparkRDDWriteClient.upsert(SparkRDDWriteClient.java:159)
at org.apache.hudi.DataSourceUtils.doWriteOperation(DataSourceUtils.java:214)
at org.apache.hudi.HoodieSparkSqlWriter$.write(HoodieSparkSqlWriter.scala:275)
at org.apache.hudi.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:164)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:180)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:132)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:438)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:293)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 8) (10.42.5.12 executor 1): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.f of type scala.Function3 in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.checkObjectFieldValueTypes(Unknown Source)
```

... there is more if you would like to see the entire error

EDIT:

I fixed this issue by correcting my jar versions between my Operator and Drivers. The jars needed to be loaded onto the image on build instead of using the spark submit dependencies section.